# Transfer browser tabs from Firefox to Google Chrome

Tags: command-line, firefox, google-chrome

If Google Chrome and Firefox are both running, is there any way to transfer all browser tabs from Firefox to Google Chrome? I want to write a shell script that will transfer all tabs from Firefox to Google Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674633/how-can-i-get-list-of-open-tabs-in-firefox-via-a-command-line-application

Comment: If you want to do the reverse of this (transferring the tabs from Google Chrome to Firefox), then the following question may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968271/chrome-on-linux-query-the-browser-to-see-what-tabs-are-open

Comment: To open the page `http://www.facebook.com/` in a new Chrome tab, you would use the following command: `google-chrome http://www.facebook.com`.

Answer (score 4):

Following the idea given in the comments (getting the links from the `sessionrestore.js` file in the FF profile dir), here is a Bash script with embedded Python to open the current tabs in Google Chrome:

```
google-chrome $(cat ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/sessionstore.js | python -c """
import sys, json
jsobj = json.loads(sys.stdin.read())
for tab in jsobj['windows'][0]['tabs']:
        print tab['entries'][0]['url'],
        """)
```

Please note that although the script works alright, it isn't verifying anything. But a more robust version of this would check the existence of file `sessionrestore.js`, verify the result of loading the JSON file and its contents, and so on.

Comment: This looks interesting, thanks. What do you mean when you say that the script isn't verifying anything?

Comment: I mean it does not verifies if the file `sessionrestore.js` exists, before trying to load. A more robust script would first check if the file exists, something like `[ -f PATH/TO/sessionrestore.js ] || { echo "sessionrestore not found!"; exit 1; }`, things like this.

Answer (score 2):

Install the Xmarks extension on both Firefox and Chrome. Besides synchronizing your bookmarks across the browsers you'll be able to use the function "Open remote tabs" which does precisely what you want.